# Turbolinks and multiple yield regions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a rails 4 application that utilizes turbolinks and a layout with multiple yielding regions. Since my `page_header` is going to have some unique styling applied to it, I wan't it to render in a separate container than where the rest of my view code is going to be rendered, e.g.:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
%html
  %body
    %header
      = yield :header
    .main
      = yield
```

**app/views/application/home.html.haml**

```
= content_for :header do
  %h1 Home
/ the rest of my view code to be rendered in the main yield goes below here...
```

This proves to be a bit of a challenge with turbolinks, as only the content within the main yield tag is updated when the page changes. This produces the effect of content in my header yield loading fine on the first page load, but for all subsequent pages I only see my main yield.

Is there an easy workaround for this?

**Edit:**
I realize I could probably just keep this simple and change the css so that my header has to give it the visual effect I need even if it is being loaded in the same yield region. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, however, and it would be preferable if I didn't have to break the grid system for my header element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't directly solve the problem, adding the `data-no-turbolink` attribute to the home page link as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks) allows me to opt-out of turbolinks and render my separate yield regions as expected for my home page while still being able to take advantage of turbolinks for the rest of my application.